# Change hover color on all charts Ag-Grid

Tags: ag-grid, ag-grid-react

I'm currently trying out AG-Grid, and can't seem to find where to change the yellow hover color on the charts.

Take a look at the plnkr and hover over the doughnut chart and see what I mean.

I the docs I'm able to read that it should be

```
    item: {
      fill: 'red',
      stroke: 'maroon',
      strokeWidth: 4
    },
    series: {
        dimOpacity: 0.2,
        strokeWidth: 2
    }
}
```

But I can't seem to get it to work on all charts.

Any suggestions?

https://plnkr.co/edit/2e8RxPabCWKJdzsn?open=main.ts&preview

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may have been adding the highlight style to the wrong place. Try the following code which should highlight fill using red:

```
  pie: {
    series: {
      highlightStyle: {
        item: {
          fill: 'red',
          stroke: 'maroon',
          strokeWidth: 4,
        },
        series: {
          dimOpacity: 0.2,
          strokeWidth: 2,
        },
      },
      title: {
        enabled: false,
      },
      label: {
        enabled: false,
      },
    },
  },
},
```

[Updated Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/wR5HCDUztiD9KKfT?open=main.ts).

Comment: Thanks for the answer, this was indeed the problem. Thanks for the solution.